# Is there a limit to PowerShell Variable?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am having a strange issue when running a pretty simple PS command using a couple of variables.

It seems I am hitting some kind of a Variable length/size limit. The command is:

```
Set-TransportRule -Name $ruleName -Priority 0 -FromScope "NotInOrganization" -HeaderMatchesMessageHeader From -HeaderMatchesPatterns $AllRecipients -ExceptIfHeaderMatchesMessageHeader From -ExceptIfHeaderMatchesPatterns $AllExcluded
```

The problematic variable is $AllExcluded which contains the content of a .TXT file which has 578 lines of data in it (email addresses).

The error I am getting is this:

```
    New-TransportRule : An Active Directory Constraint Violation error occurred on SERVER1.xxx.local Additional information: A value for the attribute was not  in the acceptable range of values. Active directory response: 00002082: AtrErr: DSID-03151817, #1:
    0: 00002082: DSID-03151817, problem 1005 (CONSTRAINT_ATT_TYPE), data 0, Att 18be851d (msExchTransportRuleXml):len 82234 At C:\Scripts\ExchangeAntiSpoof.ps1:21 char:1
+ Set-TransportRule -Name $ruleName -Priority 0 -FromScope "NotInOrganization" ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-TransportRule], ADConstraintViolationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=SERVER1,RequestId=bd498e83-0c28-440c-b785-f87cba474882,TimeStamp=18/05/2021 5:14:15 AM] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-ADConstrain     tViolationException] 2694C325,Microsoft.Exchange.MessagingPolicies.Rules.Tasks.NewTransportRule
```

I've spent a fair bit of time trying to get around this but without luck.

Essentially, all I am trying to do is update an existing Transport rule on scheduled bases with a list of exclusions, but it seems the list is simple too big, as removing about 10 items fixes the problem.

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: This has nothing to do with a variable limit: this is caused because of limits with the size of your rule. Since these are saved in AD you encounter this error (the error is pretty clear in explaining the problem)

Comment: Wow, of course. No idea how I missed that! There I was thinking it's a throughput issue of some sort because of the size of the command. Thanks bluuf, legend!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, managed to resolve the issue by splitting the actions setting up 2 Transport rules instead of 1 to deal with the AD character limit.